# Browser game PHP+MySQL increasing resource every second

Tags: php, mysql, database, browser

I'm create a small browser game and I'm programming the resource handler.
I'm using PHP and MySQL database.
I realised that I can't update the database every second to increase my resources, so reading on Stackoverflow, I found this post:

> I am also trying to make a online game in PHP and encounter also this
>   problem. My solution was actualy pretty simple. In Assuming you are
>   using different city's or planets, you will need a database table for
>   the city/planet. In this database you store the current resources and
>   the resources per hour. And also a timestamp.
>
> > For upgrading resources facility (gold mine for example) i have a
> >     database that has all the building ques with a begin time and end
> >     time.
> >
> > i then have made a page that i include on every page in the game. It
> >     first checks if there
> >      are any building ques for the selected city that
> >     should be finished since last time database was entered. If that gold
> >     mine was finished at let say 12.00 and the timestamp on your city was
> >     11.00 and current time is 13.00. What the page does, it calculates all the resources for the time 11.00 to 12.00. Then it will update the
> >     gold per hour in the city table. And then it recalculates the
> >     resources from 12.00 to 13.00.
>
> when all the above is done, it puts the timestamp on current. But as
>   you have all the resources per hour from the second run, you can store
>   it in an array and let a local timer run to update the resources on
>   screen. But since you include the above mentioned page on every page,
>   when you go to the next page it will acces the database to see what
>   the current resources should be. So the local data is only for
>   viewing.
>   By DutchEcho

This is the link: [LINK](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/82565/increasing-resources-overtime-for-a-browser-based-game)

I programmed the events queue and everything is fine. The problem, now, is to increase the resource if the player is online.
If I save the `last_login` of the player by `time()` and then I calculate the new amount of production I have a problem:

```
"UPDATE `stats` SET `rock` = `rock`+(('".time()."' - $last_login)*$rock_production)
```

I do: time() - $last_login. If I save the last_login every time a player reloads or changes page, this difference will be always 0.
Because the two times are equal.
How can I increase my resource every second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than updating last_login on each page load, only update when you start a session. You might have a second field that you update on each page load, and use the difference for your calculation. The two fields could also be used to indicate the duration of the most recent "time on line" even after the user disconnects.

**[edit]:**

How about using an update trigger? In a single statement you would have both values of last_login available - the new value and the original value.

Comment: hello , thank you for answering. I can do this , but i think my problem will be the same. I' ll always calculate a 0-difference and also , i can't use the last_login (saved  when i start a session ) cause in the difference between last_login and current_time , the player probably spend some resource.

Comment: is that the hole query ? so you will update all ROWs

Comment: So, calculate the amount earned while online, then subtract the amount used (spent) to get the current amount. In other words, use the last_login to determine how long they're online, and therefore earning "rock", then reduce that by what they have spent. Keep it simple. If you're constantly moving the starting point, it will be really easy to not give them credit they should receive. Alternately, you could read the record, grab the value in last_login, then update the record. That, IMHO would be much more resource intensive.

Comment: If you choose that route, I would suggest a stored proc to do the update that way it is done in a single call from your code.